# Query next 30 records by alphabetical order

Tags: mysql

Let say I retrieve my list of data...

**First**

```
$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 0,30");
```

From there I am using AJAX/jQuery to to append an additional 30 records. Which I need to call another file where the query will pick up where I left off.

**Second**

```
$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE name < '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['lastRecord'])."' ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 0,30");
```

My question is, if I have the first query order the first 30 by name, how can I write the second query to pick up where I left off in that order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the LIMIY like this - LIMIT 30, 30

BTW, you tagged this as jQuery and it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This option is good for short tables, but in a long tables this will give bad performance.
Every query (like that) you execute will do full table scan with `filesort` which takes some time.

I think you need to read the table once, and put the result in a temporary table (already sorted) with some `index` column and then use `WHERE index BETWEEN $number AND ($number+30)`.

Comment: Yes this example is for smaller tables. Good suggestion. I will keep this in mind for future reference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a WHERE clause to your query, you just need to use LIMIT to slice out the chunks of results you want. Limit is used to limit your MySQL query results to those that fall within a specified range. You can use it to show the first X number of results, or to show a range from X - Y results. The syntax is `Limit X, Y` where X is the starting point and Y is the number of records to retrieve.

For example:

```
$Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 90,30");
```

would retrieve 30 records beginning with the 91st (records are zero indexed).

Answer (score 0):

The first number in the LIMIT clause is the offset, starting at 0. So, your first query is correctly `LIMIT 0, 30` to get the first 30.

Simply increase the offset by `30` to start at record `31`, so to get 30 more do `LIMIT 30, 30`.

For the third page, it would be `LIMIT 60, 30`, etc.

If you need a `page x of n` type display, issue a `COUNT(*)` first to get the total number of rows, but understand that the actual rows and row count may change if rows are being inserted or deleted between calls.